# DrRacket wont start

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to begin writing scheme in DrRacket.  I had DrRacket working for a short period of time, then I got up to go get coffee, came back and now it won't start.  Instead of bringing up the DrRacket user interface when I click on DrRacket.exe, it brings up a console box with the following text:

`read-bitmap: expects type <path-string or input-port> as 1st argument, given: '#
(#<procedure:draw-honu> 270 270); other arguments were: 'unknown/alpha #f #t`

[Exited. Close box or Ctrl-C closes the console.]

I've tried reinstalling with no success.  I've also ensured I've got the 64 bit version as opposed to the 32 bit version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug from a splash-screen easter egg.  The easiest way to avoid this is to change the date for today.  (Apologies for the hassle, it will probably get fixed today, but unfortunately that won't help many people today...)

Update: see the relevant [announcement](http://lists.racket-lang.org/announce/archive/2012/000067.html) about this bug, and how to fix it.

Further update: the installers on our web pages are now patched with the fix.

Comment: What does it mean for today? change the date of the computer clock to which date?

Comment: You can change it to yesterday, and restore it tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response!

Comment: If I hadn't seen this question, I would have missed out on the Easter egg, since I usually use Emacs for Scheme (including Racket).